# Setting state of Date Picker onChange

Tags: javascript, reactjs, datetime, onchange

I am trying to update my two states based on the currently selected date using html date picker. The two states; startdate and enddate, none of them is getting updated onChange. Based on those updated states, I need to fetch data using those states data as query paramters. It consoles only initial state dates.

Here is the code:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

export default class Main extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();


    var date = new Date();


    var newdate =
      date.getFullYear() +
      "-" +
      ("0" + (date.getMonth() + 1)) +
      "-" + 
      ("0" + (date.getDate())) ;



    this.state = {
      startdate: newdate,
      enddate: newdate,
      clicked: false
    };
  }


  setStartDate = e => {
      this.setState({
        startdate: e.target.value
      })

      console.log(this.state.startdate, 'STARTDATE');
  }



  setEndDate = e => {
    //console.log(e.target.value)

    this.setState({
      enddate: e.target.value,
    });

    console.log(this.state.enddate, 'ENDDATE');
    axios.post('http://132.148.144.133:5000/api/v2/resources/sentiments', {
        sentiment_type: 'positive',
        startdate:this.state.startdate,
        enddate: this.state.enddate
    })
    .then( (result) => {

        console.log(result.data)
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log(err)
    })
  }


  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <label>From</label>
        <input
          type="date"
          name="startdate"
          value={this.state.startdate}
          onChange={this.setStartDate}
        />

        <label>To</label>
        <input
          type="date"
          name="enddate"
          value={this.state.enddate}
          onChange={this.setEndDate}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I have got to fetch the data as soon as the second input box gets updated with the selected date from the picker.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give it a try with this code:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

export default class Main extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    const date = new Date();
    const newDate =
      date.getFullYear() +
      "-" +
      ("0" + (date.getMonth() + 1)) +
      "-" +
      ("0" + date.getDate());

    this.state = {
      startDate: newDate,
      endDate: newDate
    };
  }

  handleDateChange = ({ target: { name, value } }) => {
    this.setState({
      [name]: value
    });

    if (name === "endDate") {
      const { endDate, startDate } = this.state;
      axios
        .post("http://132.148.144.133:5000/api/v2/resources/sentiments", {
          sentiment_type: "positive",
          startdate: startDate,
          enddate: endDate
        })
        .then(result => {
          console.log(result.data);
        })
        .catch(err => {
          console.log(err);
        });
    }
  };

  render() {
    const { endDate, startDate } = this.state;
    console.log(this.state);
    return (
      <>
        <label>From</label>
        <input
          type="date"
          name="startDate"
          value={startDate}
          onChange={this.handleDateChange}
        />
        <label>To</label>
        <input
          type="date"
          name="endDate"
          value={endDate}
          onChange={this.handleDateChange}
        />
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

It's cleaner with a generic method that manages your date changes. I also felt free to refactor it a bit. Let me know if it works the way you wanted it to.

Comment: It's still the same. The setState updates the state after I select the second date. Which I understands that setState sometimes doesn't promise immediate state updation.

Comment: It works perfectly for me, check out the [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/embed/dank-frog-t5105). You can add a `console.log(this.state)` in you `render()` method to see that the component is re-rendered each time you change a date.

Comment: Even I did the same :/. Anyways, Thanks for the solution :) I also figured out another way i.e. to use async await with the onChange function

Comment: No problem. I updated the solution to include the `axios` call. Give it a try it now.

Answer (score 1):

i think you should try instead of `this.setStartDate` , `(e)=> this.setStartDate(e)` and for other one too

Answer (score 1):

Answered for 3 years, but I just want to add a Typescript + Functional Component example. I use MomentJS for parsing Date to string.
By the way, I don't think firing axios.post everytime a user change the end date is a good idea. Perhaps they may pick a wrong value. Why not a post button?

```
import moment from "moment"

const YourFC = (): JSX.Element => {
  //The input type date accepts only "YYYY-MM-DD" format
  const now = moment(new Date()).format("YYYY-MM-DD")

  const [startDate, setStartDate] = useState<string | undefined>(now)
  const [endDate, setEndDate] = useState<string | undefined>(now)

  const post = ():void => {
    axios
    .post("http://132.148.144.133:5000/api/v2/resources/sentiments", {
      sentiment_type: "positive",
      startdate: startDate,
      enddate: endDate
    })
    .then(result => {
      console.log(result.data);
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
    });
  }

  return (
    <>
      <Input
        type={"date"}
        value={startDate}
        onChange={(e: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => setStartDate(e.currentTarget.value)}
      />
      <Input
        type={"date"}
        value={endDate}
        onChange={(e: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => setEndDate(e.currentTarget.value)}
      />
      <Button onClick={post}>Post</Button>
    </>
  )
}
```